# Two queries in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, windows-8, cordova, indexeddb

I have a problem with this code.

```
function checklistAntesdesalirUsuario() {

if (plataforma == plataformaW8) {
    while (db == null)
        db = abrirDB();

    var transactionUsuario = db.transaction(storeCLAntesDeSalirUsuarioNombre, "readonly");
    var transaction = db.transaction(storeCLAntesDeSalirNombre, "readonly");

    var objectStoreAntesDeSalirUsuario = transactionUsuario.objectStore(storeCLAntesDeSalirUsuarioNombre);
    var objectStoreAntesDeSalir = transaction.objectStore(storeCLAntesDeSalirNombre);

    var requestUsuario = objectStoreAntesDeSalirUsuario.openCursor();
    var request = objectStoreAntesDeSalir.openCursor();

    var cursor;
    var cursorUsuario;
    var count = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var cargadoUsuarios = false;

    var queryChecklistAntesdesalirUsuario = new Array();

    request.onsuccess = function (evt)
    {
        cursor = evt.target.result;
        seguir();
    };

    request.onerror = function(evt)
    {
        console.log("ERROR!");
    }
    requestUsuario.onsuccess = function (evt2)
    {
        cursorUsuario = evt2.target.result;
        cargadoUsuarios = true;
        seguir();
    };
    requestUsuario.onerror = function(evt)
    {
        console.log("ERROR!");
    }

    function seguir()
    {
        if (!cursor || !cargadoUsuarios)
         return;

        if (cursorUsuario && cursor.value.id_check == cursorUsuario.value.id_check) {

            cursorUsuario.continue();
        }
        else  {
            cursor.continue();
        }

        if (cursor && cursorUsuario && cursor.value.id_check == cursorUsuario.value.id_check) {
            var antesdesalir = new CLFinal(cursor.value.id_check, cursor.value.descripcioncheck, cursorUsuario.value.tarearealizada);
            queryChecklistAntesdesalirUsuario[i] = antesdesalir;
            i++;
            pintarListaChecklistAntesdesalirUsuario(queryChecklistAntesdesalirUsuario);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying is to get data from 2 storages. Sometimes the "cursor" gets data, and when "cursor.continue()" executes is OK, but other times it crashes.

I don't know what to do...

Can anyone  help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain what you want to accomplish?

Why 2 transactions? you can do everything with one. Just open the transaction with both objectstores in scope.

Why 2 cursors? You can use only one and retrieve the value you want in the second object store by using a get. You can do this on primary key or using an index

```
var transaction = db.transaction([storeCLAntesDeSalirUsuarioNombre, storeCLAntesDeSalirNombre], "readonly");

var objectStoreAntesDeSalirUsuario = transaction.objectStore(storeCLAntesDeSalirUsuarioNombre);
var objectStoreAntesDeSalir = transaction.objectStore(storeCLAntesDeSalirNombre);
```

Comment: I have tried to open both objectstores, but with no result. Could you show me an example? Thanks!

Comment: I added an example in my post